# enumerateChildNodesWithName not working

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

```
-(void) checkCollisions {
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"minion" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
        SKSpriteNode *minion = (SKSpriteNode *)node;
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(minion.frame, CGRectMake(100, 100, 800, 900))) {
             [minion removeFromParent];
             NSLog(@"removed");
       }
  }];
}
```

Hi Can anyone help with the above code it is not enumerating through my Sprites on screen. The checkCollision is definitely being called:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
     [self checkCollisions];
}
```

and I have added the SKSpriteNode, where it is created like so:

```
 [self addChild:_minion];
```

Comment: Are the child nodes named "minion"? Does it enumerate nodes (add a log)? Keep in mind that frame is in parent's coordinate system, so you're testing if the minion's frame is offset by 100x100 to 900x1000 from its parent position.

Comment: No it doesn't enumerate the Nodes I added a NSLog

Comment: Are the children named "minion" ? Meaning did you assign it that name via - `_minion.name = @"minion";` ?

Comment: Ahh I didn't realise you had to actually name the Node _minion.name = @"minion" Great thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm @LearnCocos2D I understood the frame offset that was just something I had thrown in to test. I have done it by checking the minion.position.x and y but I am not sure if this is the most efficient way. I would have thought it would have been better to add to the sprite class in the first place, something like [minion outOfBoundsDestroy:YES]

Comment: Why are you not using the inbuilt system for collision detection in Sprite Kit? It will be cleaner...

Comment: Sorry because I don't know how to use Collision detection for the screen bounds. I did post an earlier question asking how to do it but got no replies. I also could not find any documentation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173850/ios-skspritenode-leave-screen