# How do I detect if a label node is not in the scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a bunch of label nodes with physicsbodies, that sometimes glitch out of the screen for some reason. Whenever that happens I want them to come back. I tried this by detecting when their x and y are greater than the screen or less.

This didn't work because every label is a child of a labelcontainer node that has another coordinate system (I need this node for other reasons, so I can't get rid of it).

How can I detect when a label has left the scene?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS SKSpriteNode - Leave screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173850/ios-skspritenode-leave-screen)

Comment: I would focus on what this glitch is and how to fix it instead of trying to re-adjust their position.

Comment: Yeah, well I can't really fix it since it's a problem with the framework. I just have physicsbodies I can move with my finger and when I keep trying to push them out of the frame they eventually go through. The scene has an edgeloop physicsbody

Comment: Are you adding your nodes as children to self or to a worldNode?

Comment: im adding em to self

Comment: So why do you have a problem detecting coordinates relative to the self.view?

Comment: Sorry, I'm adding the labelcontainer to self, the labels themselves are being added to the labelcontainer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75582/discussion-between-sangony-and-squid).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is inside the frame of the skscene by checking the position inside the frame);

```
CGPoint point = someNode.position;
if (CGRectContains(self.frame, point))
    NSLog(@"Contains Node");
else
    NSLog(@"Does not contain Node");
```

This doesnt test if their whole frame is out of the view but if their center point is